# Why isn't @DisplayName working for me in JUnit 5?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, junit, junit5

For some reason, I'm really having a hard time getting display names to actually be respected in JUnit 5 with Kotlin. 
Here's a test file I created for the purpose of example:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@DisplayName("Example Test")
class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    @DisplayName("test name")
    fun myTest() {
        Assertions.assertThat(false).isTrue()
    }
}
```

But instead of these names being used, it's showing the actual class/method name as if they weren't annotated with `@DisplayName` at all. Here's the output from `./gradlew test`:

```
project.path.ExampleTest > myTest() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at ExampleTest.kt:12

25 tests completed, 1 failed

> Task :test FAILED
```

I keep thinking there must be something wrong with my Gradle configuration, but the setup is pretty simple so I don't know what I could be doing wrong.
Here's my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.60"
    id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "2.1.2"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.3.60"
}

version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.14.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Really scratching my head at this point, so any ideas would be appreciated. It's not using the names I give to my dynamic tests either (in conjunction with `@TestFactory`), which is particularly annoying.

Comment: I just realized it's possible that this never works in the Gradle runner. But it's definitely supposed to work in IntelliJ and it's not showing up there either.

Comment: The display name should appear in the test html report generated by Gradle, and in the JUnit view of IntelliJ (it does here). Note that in Kotlin, it's common practice to not use DisplayName, and to use a method name between backticks: `@Test
    fun \`test name\`()`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, it's not showing up in either of them. I'm actually doing the thing with the backticks in most places, but I still would like to be able to set display names for test classes (for nice nesting), or with dynamically generated tests, and none of that is working.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, I lied to you. It is showing up in the HTML report, just not in IntelliJ. Hmmm.

Answer (score 24):

Finally figured this out. It was an IntelliJ configuration issue. (The display names are never displayed in the command line anyway apparently.)

Turns out I had it configured to use the Gradle test runner instead of the IntelliJ one, which doesn't show custom display names. The solution was to go into IntelliJ settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and under "Run tests using" select "IntelliJ IDEA"

Thanks go to JBNizet for pointing out that display names are supposed to show up in the HTML test report that Gradle generates but not in the command line, which helped me determine that this was an IntelliJ-specific issue.

Comment: For me I have Intellj, but still can't see Display Name

Comment: @SanJaisy Just make sure to restart Intellij so that the changes can take effect.

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan for this post. I am so frustrated by this as it still not working for me. I'm writing dynamic tests in Kotlin and can see display names in HTML report, but still not in IntelliJ. I did change the setting + restarted IDE. Any other ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer on where to find the options but it didn't worked too. I can't still see the display names

Answer (score 5):

It's because IntelliJ uses gradle test runner by default and it does not allow custom display name.

The solution is really simple you just need to change the default test runner from "Gradle" to "IntelliJ Idea".

- Preferences
- Build, Execution, Deployment
- Build Tools
- Gradle
- Run tests using  = IntelliJ Idea

[How to change default test runner in IntelliJ Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DU7z.png)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Thests showing properly]

Truth is, for me, after I undid the changes suggested on this post and selected the check icon to the right of the green play button, the description of the tests started to show.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working in surefirereports by using the configuration
in
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Surefire_Extensions_and_Reports_Configuration_for_.40DisplayName

it displays output like this
"name" is from @DisplayName

Comment: -<testcase time="0.033" name="This is sample test" classname="io.javabrains.utils.MathUtilsTest">


-


-<testcase time="0.033" name="This is sample test"