# Problems with junit5 - @DisplayName dont show the testName

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

Im trying to show the specific description for my testcase in junit5 using the annotation @DisplayName. However, after execution junit work fine but dont show the description that I wrote. Im using IntellijIdea with Gradle for this.

```
@Test
@Category(RegressionTests.class)
@Order(order = 1)
@DisplayName("Filtrar Relatório de Vendas Por Período")
public void filtrarRelatorioPorPeriodo() throws Exception {
    home.clicarAbaVendas();
    vendas.clicarRelatorioVendas();
    vendas.clicarFiltros();
    filtrosRelatorioVendas.filtrarPorDias();
    filtrosRelatorioVendas.aplicarFiltros();
    //filtrosRelatorioVendas.selecionarUltimaData();

    tirarPrint(appium.driver,testName.getMethodName(), nomeClasse);
    //Validar se o ultimo elemento encontrado está dentro do período selecionado

}
```

Name showed in junit execution.:

filtrarRelatorioPorPeriodo

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012529/4433222?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in the IDE. Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190800